# Vaadin Exception - Couldn't find the definiton of the element with tag "vaadin-crud" in any template file declared using '@JSModule' annotations

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin, crud

[My vaadin error - Couldn't find the definiton of the element with tag "vaadin-crud"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ85f.png)

When I try to run my web application which use vaadin crud operations that pro subscription is paid, I am getting the error shown in pic. Actually, I use other page of my application which uses vaadin's free component.

To fix this issue, I reduced my vaadin framework's version from 14.9.4 to 14.8.9 and everything came back to normal.
However, I am still wondering why this exception (or error) happened in version 14.9.4?
Why did I get this error when I tried to open crud used page?

Solution: I don't know why it's happening but I guess it's vaadin's bug. To solve this problem I downgraded the version of vaadin in pom.xml file. The old and bugless version is 19.8.9 therefore I changed version from 19.8.4 to 19.8.9.

Comment: Isn't that a commercial feature?  Have you only added the `vaadin-core`
artifact instead of `vaadin`?  Also make sure to clean and _deep_ clean
(depend on your build-tool, usually something like `vaadinClean`).

Comment: Yes its commercial but the problem is not about commercial things. I have checked, the added artifact is vaadin and I made clean operation but did not deep clean.  Now I will do deep clean. thnk you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The solution is the downgrade vaadin version from 19.9.4 to 19.8.9. I am not sure why this bug is happened but this workaround is worked for me. Probably this is a vaadin bug.